# AJAX Uncaught reference error

Tags: javascript, ajax

Script.js:

```
var request = new XMLHttprequest(); 

request.open('GET','data.txt',false);   

if(request.status===200) {   
    console.log(request);   
    document.writeln(request.responseText);
}
```

This is my javascript file. I am getting this error:

> Uncaught reference error:XMLHttprequest is not defined

Please help.

Sincere thanks.

Comment: You spelled `XMLHttpRequest` wrong, it spelt with a capital `R`

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive

Comment: Also `console.log(request)` would give [object XHR..]. Try logging the `readyState` property instead

Comment: @c.P.u1 in IE, `console.dir(request)` would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried this it's simple mistake,

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
```

dont use the simple letter for xmlHttpRequest. It should be a XMLHttpRequest. Also your simple r should be a capital R. it's work for me.Also try a different version of browser.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
var request = new XMLHttprequest();
```

Should be:

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
                       //^ Capital 'R'
```

Case in JavaScript, like most languages, matters

Comment: @shivratnakumar what browser and version are you testing on?

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");//this is for ie
    } catch (e) {
            try {
                  xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");//this is for ie
                 } catch (E) {
                         try{
                              xmlhttp =new XMLHttpRequest();//for browsers other than ie
                    }
                 catch(e)
                 {

                 }
                }
```

For browsers like ie XMLHttpRequest doesnt work

Answer (score 0):

Try the following method to get your XML HTTP Request:

```
    function GetXmlHttpObject()
{ 
 try {
   var xmlHttp = null;
   if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
   {
     // If IE7, Mozilla, Safari, etc: Use native object
     xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest()
   }
   else 
   {
     if (window.ActiveXObject)
     {
       // ...otherwise, use the ActiveX control for IE5.x and IE6
       xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); 
     }
   }

   return xmlHttp;
 } catch(e)
 {
   alert(e.message);
 }
}
```